# systemd dbus service continuously updates system time

Tags: centos, systemd, date, systemd-timer

I am trying to set my centos vm's date to 1 months prior date for some license validation,
for that I have disabled  `systemd-timesyncd` and ntpd service but still after setting the time to -32 days the system dbus service resets it to current time

```
Nov  5 18:16:27 dev-sunset-racer-2 systemd: Time has been changed
Nov  5 18:16:27 dev-sunset-racer-2 systemd-timedated: Changed local time to Thu Nov  5 18:16:27 2020
Nov  5 18:17:17 dev-sunset-racer-2 dbus[3105]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service'
Dec  7 18:17:24 dev-sunset-racer-2 systemd: Time has been changed
Dec  7 18:17:43 dev-sunset-racer-2 dbus[3105]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out
Dec  7 18:20:01 dev-sunset-racer-2 dbus[3105]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service'
Dec  7 18:20:26 dev-sunset-racer-2 dbus[3105]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out
```

Any suggestion how to overcome this?

commands used:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd
sudo systemctl stop ntpd
sudo systemctl disable ntpd
sudo timedatectl set-time -- '-32 days'
```

Comment: Just curious, where do you see evidence of the dbus service *resetting* the time? All I see so far are messages from dbus saying that it was activated and failed due to timeouts, with a message from systemd itself about the time being changed.

Comment: Systemd is changing the time. Was  assuming systemd calling dbus is causing time change